# Lightweight Renderfarm Software

Tags: rendering

I recently setup my server to act as a headless rendering server, mostly to
offload long-running rendering jobs such that I could use my primary desktop for
other things.

However, I would also like to share this resource with my not-so-tech-savvy
brother somehow, without me having to manually receive a `.blend` file and
rendering it on the server.

What I'm envisioning is some kind of server application with a web-interface
that I can expose (with appropriate security measures in place, of course) to
which `.blend` files could be submitted and resulting renders be downloaded
from. Does something like that already exist?

(Obviously, [Flamenco](https://flamenco.blender.org/) seems to be the most appropriate solution for this, but
after a bit of digging, it really seems to be a "on-premise" solution. While I
**could** setup [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) to handle that, that path seems a bit overkill for what I
want to achieve.)

Comment: This is a Q&A site for problems using Blender and its built-in addons **only**. If you want to ask about external software you'll have to ask elsewhere.

Comment: In that case, you may want to update the https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to reflect that, and point to the correct sub-site.

Comment: This is probably a best fit for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/